# Zend Autoloader doesn't work when using with command prompt (CLI)

Tags: php, zend-framework, autoload

I am facing an issue with Zend_Loader_Autoloader, it is working fine when I am running application through my web browser. I tested with few of my modules. However I do have some php scripts to run as a cron job. When I am trying to remove the require_once lines and let zend autoloader to work it fails to load the classes. I am totally frustrated about this problem, if I am doing something wrong or do I need to change my approach. and why this doesn't simply work.

Comment: @Florent I get missing class. class not found

Comment: Can you paste **the full error log**?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the php.ini files differ between apache sapi and cli versions. Maybe different values for safe_mode, include_path and/or open_basedir.

Answer (score 1):

This code is working for me :

```
define('WWW_PATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/../..');

set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(realpath(WWW_PATH . '/library'), get_include_path())));

require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';

$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

$autoloader->registerNamespace('Zend_');
```